# Paraview: How to display two surfaces from one data file

Tags: paraview

I have data in multiple vtk files consisting of a time series of two 2D-fields and i want to visualise both these fields in one 3D Render in paraview as two surfaces.

The question is how to plot two surfaces (shifted by some z-value) in paraview?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Translation property under the Display section of the Properties panel to shift one of the surfaces.

Comment: Thanks I have found it. Works great!